# Authentication failed. OpenBucket in couchbase

Tags: node.js, couchbase

My task is set up a couchbase server using node.js with two endpoints. 
When i would like connecting a bucket 
I got the error shown as follows:

> CouchbaseError: Authentication failed. You may have provided an invalid username/password combination
>     message: 'Authentication failed. You may have provided an invalid username/password combination',
>     code: 2

And my code app.js is as follows

```
var express = require("express");
var couchbase = require("couchbase");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://localhost');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('example'); //the name of bucket is 'example'
bucket.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Bucket: CONNECT ERROR:', err);});

var app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

// create two endpoints 

app.get("/person/:id", function(req, res){
  bucket.get(req.params.id, function (error, result){
     if(error){
         console.log("error in get method");
         return res.status(400).send(error);
     }
     res.send(result); 
 });
});

app.post("/person/:id", function(req, res){
  var document = {
    firstName :req.body.firstName,
    lastName : req.body.lastName
  }
  bucket.upsert(req.params.id, function (error, result){
    if(error){
        console.log("error in post method");
        return res.status(400).send(error);
    }
    res.send(result); 
 });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Listening on port %s...", server.address().port); 
});
```

Comment: Why your `bucket.upsert(req.params.id, ...` is NOT using the `var document`?

Answer (score 5):

You need give the couchbase login credentials (cluster.authenticate) when you are making the database connection.

```
    var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://localhost');
    cluster.authenticate('username', 'password'); 
    var bucket = cluster.openBucket('database-name'); //the name of bucket
    bucket.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Bucket: CONNECT ERROR:', err);});
```

Comment: const cluster = new couchbase.Cluster("couchbase://localhost"); 
cluster.authenticate('Administrator', 'ABcd1234'); 
const bucket = cluster.openBucket("default", "ABcd1234", function(error){
    console.log('bucket connected fails '+ error);  
});
but i still have error 
Listening on port 3000...
bucket connected fails CouchbaseError: Authentication failed. You may have provided an invalid username/password combination

Answer (score 0):

We need to update authenticate details, then it work fine.

```
cluster.authenticate({username:"admin", password: "password"});
```